# Run Appium Inspector on IPA files downloaded from App Store

Tags: ios, automation, appium, inspector

I wish to know if it's possible to run Appium inspector on ipa files downloaded from App Store while running them on a real device. I think we need a dev build of the app with the device's UDID to run the inspector on the apps.

Is it possible to repackage the ipa file downloaded from app store with our custom Developer certificate so that it may allow the appium inspector to run ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use ipa files downloaded from appstore for appium. You indeed need a signed build from developers for real devices. Also it is not possible to repackage the downloaded ipa(from app store) in anyway(using your own developer certificates) to make appium inspector run on it. If this can happen then it will partially defeat the idea of the existence of the apple certificates, provisioning etc.

Comment: so what is the thing i need Ios dev to do ?